# div element height not 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I have set the body and html to height:100% and I have set the element to Height:100% and the div is only contained in html and body, nowhere else.
Yet when displaying the element is 100% of the browser window height not the site height which is scrollable. I'm sure the answer is simple but I can't think of a reason why it is like that :/

Comment: please read your question again any see whether you can understand what you have said..

Comment: when you set `body` and `html` height to 100% then you are setting them to the height of the visible part of the browser. You could try setting `min-height` on the element. What is the reason that you need the `div` to be the full height of the web page?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You set the body height to 100% of the screen height, which is why it won't scroll.

The inner element at 100% will inherit 100% of the screen size.

try removing the height of the body and use px for the element until you develop more content on the site.

Comment: Though the answer is still vague, it is correct, seeing OP is no stranger to vagueness +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking (or more likely, somebody has found this via google), I achieved what I think you are after here:

http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk/code/fullheight/demo2.htm

Its a self contained file, IE all the CSS is there with the markup, so you should be able to see what is going on.

The full article is here:

http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=312

Basically, its a layout where the footer stays at the bottom of the window (thanks to the 100% div) until the content is more than the window, in which case it scrolls with the content.